# How to make wcf service keep the data between ajax calls?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf

Suppose that I have simple WCF Service:

```
[ServiceContract]   
public interface ITestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "POST",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetStatus();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "POST",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string SetStatus(string status);    
}

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class TestService : ITestService
{
    private string _status;
    public string GetStatus()
    {
        return _status;
    }
    public string SetStatus(string status)
    {
        _status = status;
        return "completed";
    }
}
```

and the Html page that performs two ajax calls to that service:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Wcf services test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function btnSend_onclick() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Services/TestService.svc/SetStatus",
                data:'{"status":"'+jQuery("#txtSetStatus").val()+'"}',
                processData: false,
                dataType: "json",
                //If the call succeeds
                success:
        function (response) {
                jQuery("#lblInfo").text('Service returned: ' + response.SetStatusResult);
        },
                //If the call fails
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    jQuery("#lblInfo").text(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                }
            });

        }
        function btnGetStatus_onclick() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Services/TestService.svc/GetStatus",
                processData: false,
                dataType: "json",
                //If the call succeeds
                success:
        function (response) {
            jQuery("#lblGetStatus").text('Status is: ' + response.GetStatusResult);
        },
                //If the call fails
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    jQuery("#lblInfo").text(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                }
            });

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="txtSetStatus" />
<button id="btnSend" onclick="return btnSend_onclick()">Send status</button>
<span id="lblStatus"></span>
<span id="lblInfo"></span>
<br />
<button id="btnGetStatus" onclick="return btnGetStatus_onclick()">Get Current Status</button>
<span id="lblGetStatus"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

If I call SetStatus first(by typing something in txtSetStatus input and clicking Send status button), then call GetStatus(by clicking Get Current Status button), then the returned status is null. I understand that this happens because WCF service instance is created each time when a html page performs ajax request.
But what is the best practice to keep the data between 2 or more ajax calls?

Comment: The best practice is making services state less = storing status outside of your service, for example in the database.

Comment: unfortunately database wouldn't work in the scenario I am working on. The real-world scenario is the page performs POST request to WCF service(sending some data), then the page opens the new window with URL = GET request to WCF service. This get request responses with the content(type="application/pdf") which depends on the data that were sent with the 1st request. So the data are really need to be stored just between 2 calls and they don't need to be saved after that. I don't think that the database is good solution for this scenario.

Comment: and I can't send the data with the GET request because the data is the string which is very long(more than 2,048 characters which is the limit for GET url). The data may be 10000 characters or more...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found the answer. It seems that the best way is setting aspNetCompatibilityEnabled=true for my WCF service and then making use of asp.net Session object in order to keep the values temporarily:

```
public class TestService : ITestService
{
    public string GetStatus(string id)
    {
        var session = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session;
        var ret= session[id].ToString();
        session.Remove(id);
        return ret;
    }
    public string SetStatus(string status)
    {
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D");
        var session = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session;
        session.Add(guid, status);
        return guid;
    }
}
```